# Is it allowed to "bump" a post to attempt to get any kind of response?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Signal Processing Stack Exchange post: [How do 2D DCT basis functions interact to produce 8x8 JPEG tiles?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/58065/how-do-2d-dct-basis-functions-interact-to-produce-8x8-jpeg-tiles)

I feel this is a valid question (maybe not! i'm an outsider to the signal processing field of study), but I've yet to receive any kind of response: answer, comment, or upvote/downvote. Is there a way to bump the post so that it's back at the top of the questions feed? If yes, is it O.K. to bump, or is that frowned upon? Thanks in advance for your help! Please @ me in chat if this meta post is invalid and will be deleted. The mere fact and the reason for deletion are both information I'd like to possess in that specific case. :- )

thanks,

Comment: Related help center: [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you edit your question it automatically appears at the top under the 'active' tab. I think that editing a question (and, hopefully, improving it) is a good and correct way to give it more attention.